# Why have separate quadrotor and quadcopter tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I have just edited the [quadrotor tag](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags/quadrotor/info), and added *suggested* text for both the excerpt and full tag wiki, which were lacking. However, I then noticed that there was also a [quadcoptor tag](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags/quadcopter/info) (which I must say, already has a very informative description).

Are they not, essentially, one and the same thing? If there is a significant difference, then they should be edited to specify when to use each one. Otherwise, should they not be merged?

Maybe I have actually suggested the incorrect text, and actually made them sound like the same thing, in which case I apologise. If I have not, then maybe a rethink is required, with respect to these two synonymous tags.

Out of interest, at the time of writing, `quadrotor` is tagged 67 times, and `quadcopter` 228 times.

Comment: I'm happy to merge these tags if no-one can come up with a compelling reason to keep them separate.

Answer (score 1):

A quick semantic answer from my research group wiki, we focus on aerial manipulation.

> In our group we warmly encourage the use the multi-rotor family of
>   words (quadrotor, hexarotor, octorotor) instead of multi-copter one
>   (quadcopter, hexacotper, octocopter) for the following reasons:
>
> 1. etymologically helico+pter = helikos (twisted) + pteron (wing),
>      so, to be etymologically correct, one should actually say quadpter, hexapter, octopter, but those words are not used
> 2. copter is a short name for helicopter, so multi-copter could, in principle, mean a system with multiple helicopters, quadcopter with
>      four helicopters and so on.. but also in this case is not used

This being said, I agree that the two tags should be merged in one, and to enforce `quadrotor`